# Adding parcel number to site when there are many sites in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, sql, unique-id, autoincrement

I have a PostgreSQL table with 7000 records relating to grounds maintenance.

Each site has a site reference number and I want to assign a sequential parcel number within each site starting at 1 to n.

```
Siteid|parcelid
L001|1
L001|2
H001|1
H001|2
H001|3
etc.
```

I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Use of `row_number()` isn't a GIS-centric task. [dba.se] would be a better place to research this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but [add autoincremental field] in the qgis toolbox may be able to help you. It can take all fields with a specific value and assign numbers to each to create values L001 to L'n' and H001 to H'n' and so forth

Answer (score 6):

You can use row_number and partition by site:

```
--Create a test table

drop table if exists public.test;
create table public.test (id serial, siteid varchar(10));
insert into public.test (siteid)
values ('L001'),('L002'),('L002'),('L001'), ('L001');

alter table public.test add column parcelid int; --Add the new column

"id"    "siteid"    "parcelid"
1       "L001"  
2       "L002"  
3       "L002"  
4       "L001"  
5       "L001"


--Calculate parcelid

update public.test a
set parcelid = sub.parcelid
from
(select id, row_number() over(partition by "siteid") parcelid from public.test) sub
where a.id=sub.id;

"id"    "siteid"    "parcelid"
1         "L001"    1
2         "L002"    1
3         "L002"    2
4         "L001"    2
5         "L001"    3
```